# Azure AD Banned Password Password Protection lanugage support - does it do language translation for non-English?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Will Azure-AD Banned passwords or Password Protection formulate reponses or error messages to users in their language for non-English users ie. Windows devices with non-English language selected ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be translated by the browser language, not related to device language.

[image]

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.